# Format datagrid column color

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a advanced datagrid label function like this:

```
private function dgFormat(item:Object, column:AdvancedDataGridColumn):String{
var v3:int = item.value1 - item.value2;     
return "Total: " + v3;

}
```

How can I change the text color of v3 dynamically? I want it to be red if it's less than zero & black otherwise.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few ways of doing this, but personally if I were you, I'd just create a custom item renderer for the columns that you want the color to change and do something like:

```
<s:Label text="Total: {data}" color="{data < 0?0xFF0000:0x000000}" />
```

This way, you bind the difference right off the bat without having to add 'total' in your data, and bind the color change as well.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a custom item renderer for your AdvancedDataGridColumn.  The item renderer will check the value being set, and update the color of the text depending on its content.

[This](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=advdatagrid_10.html) should get you started.